# Bug when set up -setWantsLayer: on Lion

Tags: osx-lion, nsview

I have a subclass of NSView where I'm handling the -mouseDown: event to get the position of the click on the screen. With this position I defined a point that I'll use to draw a rect on the -drawRect: it's working fine.

BUT... when I set up wantsLayer the things isn't work. When I get the position of the input, I looked that Y-axis have an increase of 20 points and I don't know what's happening... Can anyone explain? How I fix this problem?

Simulation:

> I click at coordinate x: 100; y: 100; and the drawRect draws the rect on x: 100; y: 100; It's okay, it's what I want.

With setWantsLayer:YES

> I click at coordinate x: 100; y: 100; and the drawRect draws the rect on x: 100; y: 120; (or something like this)

Is possible I use CALayers without setting -setWantsLayer to YES? I'm trying figure this out but I have no idea what's happening... I need your help.

UPDATE: I'm trying figure this out and I did a lot of tests now...
Now I can say that the problem is with -mouseDown: from NSView, when I set up -setWantsLayer to YES it don't works like expected anymore...

I have on my window a CustomView and I created a subclass of NSView and set as the CustomView class. The CustomView is at position (0, 20). The coordinate orientation isn't flipped.

I believe when I set up to NSView wants layer the -mouseDown: update the frame to position (0, 0) (or in other words, it get the NSWindow frame) instead of (0, 20). When it occurs every position from -mouseDown: get an increase of 20 points on Y-axis. I don't know if what I'm saying is right, but is the facts that I'm getting as result of my tests.

Someone can help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with help of mikeash from (#macdev @ frenoode) I solved this question.

The problem was how I was converting the point return from -mouseDown: event. I was using -convertPointFromBacking: and like mikeash said: "the problem is that -convertPointFromBacking: is not correct for converting the point returned from locationInWindow". "Because locationInWindow is not in 'its pixel aligned backing store coordinate system'".

I changed to -convertPoint:fromView: like: [sender convertPoint:[mEvent locationInWindow] fromView: nil]; and it's working nice!

Thank you to mikeash.

And I'm posting the answer here to help others with the same question.